# Apache2 rewrite module, flag [L]

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have next rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(js|css|img)/(.+\.jpg|gif|png|js|css)$ media/myfiles/$1/$2/$3 [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

I my application i have route class, that can process url's for my needs.

When i try to open file, that contains extension that will match to rewrite rule, i move to next rewrite rule, and my router class process this url...

Any ideas why apache doesn't stop after rule match first time?

P.S. first rule works after disabling second rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html

> If you are using RewriteRule in either .htaccess files or in
>    sections, it is important to have some understanding of
>   how the rules are processed. **The simplified form of this is that once
>   the rules have been processed, the rewritten request is handed back to
>   the URL parsing engine to do what it may with it.** It is possible that
>   as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or 
>   section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run
>   again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the
>   rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the
>   request process to start over.

(emph mine)

So what I think happens is that your last rule hits, and redirects. It doesn't call the bottom line. But then, the request is handled like any other request, your regexp DOESN"T hit, and in this run the bottom line DOES come into play.

This is also why it works when you disable the bottom rule: the second time around there is nothing to do, so nothing happens.

Comment: Tnx, but i didn't understand how i can disable reruns last rule using apache engine?

Comment: Well, you can't. Because after you have succesfully finished your "last" line with the regexp, you get what is basically a new request with that line. And your regexp doesn't hit, so you get your bottom line. What you CAN do is add a regexp to that last line that says something like "if NOT /media/myfiles, then ... ". You should be able to find out how to do that I assume: so instead of the `.*` you just regexp for things that are not the result of the previous line?

Comment: You need to use a rewriting condition (RewriteCond).

Comment: Yes yes yes, i know, solution: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(png|jpe?g|gif|js|css)$`
`RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php`